# watchOS2 how to set the companion settings icon

Tags: ios, watchos-2

I already set the appicon include the "Apple Watch Companion Settings",but in my iPhone and simulator's apple's watch app didn't show the setting icon,and my watch app's icon is normal,so who can help me solve this problem. thx a lot

Comment: That icon (companion settings) appears in the real iPhone in the Apple Watch app on the home screen.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having the same issue and watchOS 2.0 (13S344) hasn't fixed it for me, though it sounds like that worked for @Martijn.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.
I'm using:

- Xcode 7 <strike>beta (7A218)</strike> (7A220)
- Apple 38 mm Watch with watchOS 2.0 <strike>beta (13S343)</strike> (13S344)
- iPhone 6 with iOS 9 <strike>GM (13A340)</strike> (13A344)

Both icons (@2x and @3x) for 'Apple Watch Companion Settings' are correctly shown in the Xcode AppIcon Assets catalogue within the WatchKit App.

I hope that this is an Xcode issue. 
Because all the App Store apps that are installed on my Watch show their Setting icon properly in the companion iPhone Watch.app.

To verify this assumption, I have submitted my iOS app with Watch extension to Apple's TestFlight. It's now waiting for review.
Once it's available, I'll install the app via TestFlight to see if the Setting icons is properly shown in the iPhone Watch.app.

**UPDATE**
Tried again with final versions of Xcode 7 (7A220) and iOS 9 (13A344), but same result.

**UPDATE 2**
After updating to the public watchOS 2.0 (13S344) finally the icons are shown on the iPhone Watch.app. Even when working with Xcode.

Comment: That sounds promising. Unfortunately my app is rejected by Apple, so I first had to appeal. Hopefully today they will accept and I can verify if the TestFlight build shows the correct icons.

Comment: The issue is solved with the public watchOS 2.0 (13S344). See updated answer.

Comment: @Martijn I'm using watchOS (13S344) and it's still not working for me on the device or simulator. After resetting the simulator it shows the blank icon in watch settings even though my asset catalog has correctly sized files. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it worked for me, since after installing 13S344 I had to pair the watch again with my iPhone. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

I run WatchOS 2.

This problem did not disappear for me until I changed "Enable Bitcode" to "NO" in the build setting for the main iOS app. All the rest of the "Enable Bitcode" settings in the build settings (for project, for Watch app and for Watch App Extension), I have "Enable Bitcode" set to "YES".

My guess is that iOS App Thinning is faulty and is stripping away the companion settings asset since it is stored in the Watch App. In the xcassets collection for WatchOS All icons except the companion setting icons are aimed to be used only on WatchOS.